# Recovering tex file using tex~ file

Tags: emacs, auctex

I use Emacs AUCTEX to handle tex files. I accidentally overwrote the content of a tex file and the old content is gone. Let's say the file is file.tex. I do have the file.tex~ which was modified before getting messed up.

Is there any way to recover the old tex file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to rename file.tex~ to file.tex